# How to get all ROS log messages from rostest?

Tags: ros, moveit

I am trying to debug a problem with a rostest that it is probably failing due to multithreading, as the result of the test is always different.

That aside, my problem is that I cannot get to see the **complete** ROS logs. More specifically, I can see the logs but for **only** the first test case. The remaining tests don't show any logs.

Here is an example of what I get from the console. It shows ros logs up to the result of the first test `MoveItCppTest.SimpleSimulatenousExecutionTest`, which also always succeeds. For the remaining tests, I just get the logs of the result but nothing else.

This is the [test file](https://github.com/cambel/moveit/blob/simultaneous-trajectory-execution/moveit_ros/planning/trajectory_execution_manager/test/test_simultaneous_execution_manager.cpp) and I am executing it like this:

`rostest moveit_ros_planning test_simultaneous_execution_manager.test --text`

```shell
...
[DEBUG] [1674281108.466333224]: Event EXECUTION_COMPLETED
[DEBUG] [1674281108.724856326]: Event's group name: panda_2
[DEBUG] [1674281108.724891348]: 0 remaining active controllers for group name: panda_2
[DEBUG] [1674281108.724905334]: Clearing context with group name: panda_2
[DEBUG] [1674281108.724931419]: No active trajectories remaining
[ INFO] [1674281108.725006225]: Deleting PlanningComponent 'panda_2'
[ INFO] [1674281108.725067552]: Deleting PlanningComponent 'panda_1'
[ INFO] [1674281108.725092946]: Deleting MoveItCpp
[ WARN] [1674281108.746951670]: Stop!. stop_execution_: 0 run_event_manager_: 0
[ INFO] [1674281109.234819475]: Stopped publishing maintained planning scene.
[ INFO] [1674281109.236025658]: Stopping world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1674281109.236683101]: Stopping planning scene monitor
[ WARN] [1674281109.329307461]: SEVERE WARNING!!!
Attempting to unload /root/ros_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so
while objects created by this library still exist in the heap!
You should delete your objects before destroying the ClassLoader. The library will NOT be unloaded.
[       OK ] MoveItCppTest.SimpleSimulatenousExecutionTest (5903 ms)
[ RUN      ] MoveItCppTest.WaitForSingleTrajectory
/root/ros_ws/src/moveit/moveit_ros/planning/trajectory_execution_manager/test/test_simultaneous_execution_manager.cpp:115: Failure
Value of: moveit_cpp_ptr->getTrajectoryExecutionManager()->push(panda_1_robot_trajectory_msg)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] MoveItCppTest.WaitForSingleTrajectory (1447 ms)
[ RUN      ] MoveItCppTest.RejectTrajectoryInCollision
[       OK ] MoveItCppTest.RejectTrajectoryInCollision (1489 ms)
[ RUN      ] MoveItCppTest.RejectInvalidTrajectory
[       OK ] MoveItCppTest.RejectInvalidTrajectory (1812 ms)
[ RUN      ] MoveItCppTest.CancelTrajectory
[       OK ] MoveItCppTest.CancelTrajectory (1314 ms)
[----------] 5 tests from MoveItCppTest (11965 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 5 tests from 1 test suite ran. (11965 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] MoveItCppTest.WaitForSingleTrajectory

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Is there any way to enable logging for all tests?

Answer (score 0):

I also have issues with that, normally what I would do is search in `~/.ros/logs` for the latest logs or add some `ROS_WARN`, as that would be shown in the terminal as well

Comment: If I add ROS_WARN logs, they appear but again only for the first test case, not for any of the other ones